# Error 403 Forbidden not User-Agent

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests, user-agent

I've tried looking at previous posts on the same subject but none of the solutions seem to be working and I'd like to confirm that there is  indeed nothing I can do to get around this.

I'm a journalist trying to download permit data from off the planning authority's website. I could do this no problem up till a few months ago but the website has been changed and after adapting my code to the new site, I now seem to be getting an Error 403 every time I try to follow links on the site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code -not the best looking or  most efficient, but I'm self taught and use coding mainly for scraping data for work - stats on the page: http://www.pa.org.mt/padecisionSearch?date=1/31/2018%2012:00:00%20AM

In the bit of code I have pasted beneath I am trying to access each link permit link (first one on page: http://www.pa.org.mt/PACaseDetails?Systemkey=200414&CaseType=PA/10351/17%27) in order to scrape permit details.

While I can generate the link addresses without a problem (they are accessible by clicking the link), sending a request to the address returns:

b'\r\nForbidden\r\n\r\n

### Forbidden URL

\r\n

---

HTTP Error 403. The request URL is forbidden.

\r\n\r\n'

I've tried changing the User-Agent, and I've also tried to put in a timer between requests but nothing seems to have any effect.

Any suggestions would be very welcome

My code:

```
import  requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date, timedelta as td
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import urllib




with requests.Session() as s:
        #s.headers.update(head)
        r= s.get("http://www.pa.org.mt",data=None, headers =  {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,   like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"})

        page = (s.get("http://www.pa.org.mt/padecisionSearch?date=1/31/2018%2012:00:00%20AM", data=None, headers =  {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"}).content)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        search_1 = soup.find_all('table')
        for item in search_1:   
            item1 = item.find_all('tr')
            for item2 in item1:           
                    item3 = item2.find_all('td', class_ = 'fieldData')  

                    for element in item3:  

                        list2.append(element.text)
                        zejt_number = (len(list2)/6)
                        zi = element.find_all('a')  

                        if len(zi) == 0 and ((len(list2)-1)%5 == 0 or len(list2) == 1):  

                            case_status.append("")
                            applicant.append("")
                            architect.append("")
                            application_type.append("")
                            case_category.append("")
                            case_officer.append("")
                            case_officer2.append("")
                            date_approved.append("")
                            application_link.append("")

                        elif len(zi) != 0:   

                            for li in zi:
                                hyperlink = "http://www.pa.org.mt/"+li.get('href')
                                application_link.append(hyperlink)
                                print(hyperlink)
                                z = (s.get(hyperlink, data=None, headers =  {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"}).content)    
                                print(z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all your code is a bit messy. is it all your code? or just a part of it? e.g. you are importing pandas twice. nevertheless your main problem why this is not working is the hyperlinks you are generating:

```
for li in zi:
    hyperlink = "http://www.pa.org.mt/"+li.get('href')
    print(hyperlink)
```

the result looks like this:

```
http://www.pa.org.mt/../PACaseDetails?Systemkey=200414&CaseType=PA/10351/17'
```

this is link won't work. a quick workaround would be to edit the hyperlink before you do the request:

```
for li in zi:
    hyperlink = "http://www.pa.org.mt/"+li.get('href')
    hyperlink = hyperlink.replace('../', '')
    print(hyperlink)
    z = (s.get(hyperlink, data=None, headers =  {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"}).content)    
    print(z)
```

the hyperlinks now should look like this:

```
http://www.pa.org.mt/PACaseDetails?Systemkey=200414&CaseType=PA/10351/17'
```

and the request should pass through.